Use the Django ORM to do a left outer join between unrelated models?
Suppose I have two models:
class One(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)


class Two(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)

They are not related by a foreign key, and there are reasons to leave it that way in this project.
I want to know the One instances with a name that is not in Two.
Here is the SQL to get that:
select app_one.name
from app_one left join app_two on app_one.name = app_two.name
where app_two.name is null
group by 1;

Is it possible to get that through the ORM, or do I just have to write a query?
Note: one possible solution is to query out all the names of One, and use IN on Two.  I'd rather not do that, it scales poorly.

You can use a Subquery:
from django.db.models import Subquery

results = One.objects.exclude(name__in=Subquery(Two.objects.values("name")))

The SQL generated will be similar to
SELECT "app_one"."name"
FROM "app_one"
WHERE NOT (
    "app_one"."name" IN (SELECT U0."name" FROM "app_two" U0)
        AND "app_one"."name" IS NOT NULL
    )


Subquery. Never heard of it. Thank you!
